# Angular - Invoke a method inside a component class whenever any field in the component html is touched/modified?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component, the parent component has multiple child components inside it.. The parent component has a Save button..

The child components have field/controls like textbox and other types.

Whenever any text or any other fields in the child components are modified/touched i want to enable the Save button in the parent component.

```
<div>
   <h3>Parent Component</h3>
   <child-component1>
   </child-component1>
   <child-component2>
   </child-component2>
   <child-component3>
   </child-component3>
   <button type="submit" [disabled]="!isSaveButtonDisabled">
   Save
   </button>
</div>
```

In the child component i have a method touchDetected() which will alert the parent component on the change.

Child component.

```
class ChildComponent {

   @Output() onChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
ngOnInit() : void {

this.formGoupUser.valueChanges.subscribe((value:any) => {
  this.onChange.emit(true):
}
}  
    }
```

Child component html

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroupUser">
  /* Form elements and controls */
<form>
```

Edited : I subscribed to ValueChanges on my FormGroup so that it will update the Parent component whenever there is any change in the child component fields, the problem is on my form the fields are autopopulated initially during page load and due to this this.onChange.emit(true) is getting called before user making any change to the fields ?

How do i overcome this, so that only when user makes any changes to any of the fields on the form then only `this.onChange.emit(true)` gets called ?

Comment: If you are using reactive forms you can subscribe to valueChanges on that formGroup and check the value of properties like dirty, pristine, touched, untouched. [link](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl)

Comment: @Kitsune66 I am able to accomplish this  by subscribing to value changes form to ValueChanges inside ngOnInit() but the problem is, in my form few of the fields are autopopulated initially during page load and during that phase this ValueChanges is getting invoked and enabling the save button on my form, Is there a way i can overcome this ?

Comment: @nc_teh put a form group touched condition in your valueChanges callback before setting any values for the first time

Comment: @nc_teh can you show how you are initializing the formGroup? Do you initizalize the formGroup and autopopulate its values programatically?

Comment: @nc_teh Look for the formGroup property pristine or dirty - "A control is dirty if the user has changed the value in the UI." [angular abstract control](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#properties)

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest trying the following in the ngOnInit():

1. Try setting an internal flag in your component to indicate loading state.

   ```
    this.isLoading = true;
   ```
2. After the data is initialized, try:

   ```
    this.formGroupUser.markAsPristine();
    this.formGroupUser.markAsUntouched();
    this.isLoading = false;
   ```
3. In your valueChanges subscriber event check if still in the loading state. If not then fire the event when a change occurs:

   ```
    this.formGroupUser.valueChanges.subscribe(x => { 
        if (this.isLoading === false)
            this.touchDetected();
    })
   ```

Comment: I am facing an issue, the data to this component child component is coming as an Input property from parent component @Input user :User , i was not able to set this.isLoading = false; .. Do we have any Life cycle hook which gets  invoked once the form elements are binded so that i can use that to set this.isLoading = false; and also markAsPristine() and markAsUntouched(); ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the data from an input decorator then the following code could also be used (where Data = your data input parameter):

```
private _data: Data;  

@Input() set data(value: Data) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this._data = value;
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.formGroupUser.markAsPristine();
  this.formGroupUser.markAsUntouched();
}
```

This sets a loading flag before binding and after binding then marks the controls as pristine/untouched. It should ensure that the code within the value changes event handler is not triggered during the control binding.